# Is it a good practice to have two views file? One in the website directory and one in the app directory

Tags: django

I was wondering if it is a good practice to have two views file. I have two views files. One to serve pages like about, home etc. The other is specific to the app I am building. I have the first one where I have my settings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to make `views` as a package and then put the two files in there.

Example

```
  - myapp/
      - views/
          - __init__.py
          - first.py
          - second.py
```

and in `__init__.py`

```
from .first import A, B
from .second import C, D
```

Nothing stops you from having 2 view files, but it becomes very unmanagable after a while. By creating a package, you have all views related code at one place, and easy to extend if need be.

Comment: would that be out of the apps directory? Like where I would usually have my static folder?

Comment: No.. It should be within your app. You are just replacing the `views.py` file with `views` package

Comment: But my home and about pages have nothing to do with the app. So would they still go in to the apps folder? sorry I am new to django. so I am little confused with project styling

Comment: If you want to do it the "right" way, have them in separate apps. But, If you just want to access views, just create a package called `views` in the root level and put the files in there. That would work too. Another thing.. Look into `FlatPages` to implement your `About` sections. It would be a lot more easier